How to substantiate "to be" instead of "to have" in next sentences?

He is a good influence on our neighbors.
Mercury is generally a good influence on fellow planets.

But this sentences suggest themselves as like:

Force is an influence on an object that causes it to accelerate.
Leadership is an influence on people in order to achieve results.

Why would not write as like:

He has a good influence on our neighbors.
Mercury has generally a good influence on fellow planets.

How we can explain "to be" in that sentences instead of "to have"?
Do have "to be" - "to have" meaning in general?

One note: for some reason, when modifying "is" with an adverb, the adverb often comes after "is," like "He is always happy." But with other verbs, the adverb usually comes before the verb: "He always has a smile on his face."

Influence as a noun can be used in several ways. Oxford Languages says

the capacity to have an effect on the character, development, or behaviour of someone or something, or the effect itself.

and also

a person or thing with the capacity to have an influence on someone or something.

So 'he' in your first example can have an influence (in the first sense) or be an influence (in the second sense).

I might add that the option of two verbs does not at all show they mean the same. "To be" and "to have" do not share a meaning in general.
